# Javascript Object Behavior Won't Assign Value

Tags: javascript

Trying to assign at anonymous object but the value became 'Array(0)'

I try to console the values below
`console.log(values, { state: state, values: values })`

And got this result

```
[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']
{state: 4, values: Array(0)}
```

Why the `values` in the object became `Array(0)`?

When i `console.log(values, state)`
I got this result

```
[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']
4
```

Here i implement the code

```
function getInputsValue() {
    let state = 4;
    let values = [];

    ... some code that make `values` became `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']`

    return { state: state, values: values }
}
```

any explaination? please

Comment: `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']` doesn't seem to be a valid array?

Comment: omg, thanks for your point  there, it work normal when i change the `let values = []` to `let values = {}`, but why the console shows `values` as an object? the `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']` is the value that shown on the `console` by `console.log(values)`

Comment: You are adding non-integer keys to an array. `values["inpid"] = 'asd'`. It doesn't increase the length of the array. It just adds those keys to the array

Comment: why the first on showing an object? but the second return to it first declaration? `console.log(values, { state: state, values: values })`

Comment: Are you sure it shows `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']` and not `{inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd'}` and you are mistakenly reading it as `[ ]` ? `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']` is not valid JS

Comment: Arrays are objects, you can add arbitrary keys to them just like you can to regular objects (`{}`). When you do that, you get `[inpid: 'asd', inppwd: 'asd']` as you're adding keys to an array

Comment: aah, ok, I see what happened, @NickParsons is correct

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis im sure, just trying using console in this page, but result the same bracket `[` not '{', depends on the `let a = []` or `let a = {}` even when i trying to assign `a['asd']` on `let a = []`

Comment: thankss for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how Chrome displays a 0-length array in value summaries in the console. Empty arrays can still contain `properties`.

You are trying to add properties to an array, I recommend using plain objects instead. You can initialize the object like this:

```
let values = {
    inpId: '',
    inpPwd: ''
};
```

You can simply access the values by doing this.

```
values.inpId;
values.inpPwd;
```

This allows you to get and set the values within. The rest of the code doesnt need to be changed unless you iterate over the values array.

*Side note*

If you need the `values` object to be an array. You can simply change it to an array and add the objects into it.